# Formula of the determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

Given (finite dimensional?) vector spaces $V$ and $W$, we can define the transpose of a linear map $f:V \to W$ by the obvious map $W^* \to V^*$. Can we do a similar thing for the determinant? Can we define the determinant of an operator without making reference to a matrix, or bases? I feel we should be able to do this, given that the value of the determinant is independent of the basis chosen.

Comment: Are you aware of the alternating product of vector spaces? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#The_exterior_power

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant of a linear map $f:V\to W$ between finite dimensional vector spaces over a field $K$ **can only be defined if $V=W \; !$**
And be very careful: we really have to require  that our vector spaces be  **equal** and not merely isomorphic.

The intrinsic definition is then as follows :
If $V$ has dimension $n$ then  the top exterior power $\wedge^n V$ has dimension one so that the induced linear mapping $\wedge^n f:\wedge^n V\to \wedge^n V$ is necessarily a homothety $\omega\mapsto d \cdot\omega$ i.e. the multiplication by some scalar $d\in K$ in the base field.
And that scalar  is the required determinant: $\text {det} f\stackrel {\text {def}}{=}d$.

This approch (pioneered by Bourbaki around 1950, I think) is undoubtedly very elegant, but it requires a knowledge of multilinear algebra not taught  in elementary undergraduate courses.

Comment: What problem does it have if $V \cong W$? Surely we can still take the top exterior power on both sides?

Comment: Dear @Sanchez: yes, you can take the top exterior product of both sides but the resulting linear map is **not** a homothety. The problem is that a linear map between two different vector spaces of dimension one is not a homothety and it is **absolutely impossible** to describe it by a single scalar unless you choose a base in each or the vector spaces. This is an elementary but subtle point

Comment: Ah, I see your point. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I see that the determinant can only be defined when $V=W$. I should have been more careful.

Comment: Dear nigelvr, don't be too harsh on yourself: this is a rather delicate point, perhaps not sufficiently emphasized in books.

Comment: Well depends on what you really want to do. There is no reason to get Bourbaki on this question. In many places, the notion of a determinant of a map $T:V \rightarrow W$ between two metric spaces is used. It is usually defined up to sign but if you are OK with it there is natural way to define its absolute value (take orthonormal basis at each space). It is equivalent to looking at the induced norm $||\wedge^n (T)||$ and it measures the volume expansion of your map. You can also define it to be the product of the eigenvalues of $T^*T: V\rightarrow V$ which is uniquely defined.

Comment: Inner product spaces sorry.

Comment: @Sina: 1) My answer concerns vector spaces over an arbitrary field $K$ , over which the notion of inner product doesn't even make sense. 2) Even over $\mathbb R$ what you write depends on arbitrary choices of inner products and is not in the least canonical. 3) There is a very good "reason  to get Bourbaki on this question": that treatise is the most complete existing  reference on linear and multilinear algebra and is of the highest possible quality. Ignore it at your own risk.

Comment: Perhaps my description of being Bourbaki was not the correct point of view. There is no point in so harshly out ruling some possible definitions of the determinant. In the cases that I have in mind where some analysis is required for the iterates of some map, different inner products do not create a problem as they are equivalent and you care only about asymptotics. In any case this definition is very useful. So yes you can come up with some definition of a determinant between different vector spaces which is useful and you can find this also in literature and books.

Comment: Dear @Sina: yes, I agree that in some contexts   defining determinants thanks to supplementary structures like inner products can be interesting and  useful.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Sanchez's answer, it's useful to consider the action of a linear operator on objects created by wedge products--which represent oriented planes, volumes, and so on, just as a single vector represents an oriented line.

We generally define the action of linear operators across the wedge product as follows:

$$\underline T(a \wedge b) \equiv \underline T(a) \wedge \underline T(b)$$

The operator on a wedge product is the wedge product of the operator on the individual vectors.

Now, consider the highest-dimensional object that can be formed by wedges.  In an $N$-dimensional space, this is a wedge product of $N$ linearly independent vectors.  This object itself forms a 1d vector space---all objects of this kind are scalar multiples of each other.  For this reason, this object is often called the *pseudoscalar*.  We'll call it $i_N$.

Now, what is $\underline T(i_N)$?  First, linear operators that can be extended across wedges preserve the grade of their arguments--vectors go to vectors, planes to go planes, and the pseudoscalar can only go to (some multiple of) itself.

In other words,

$$\underline T(i_N) = \alpha i_N$$

We call the number $\alpha$ the *determinant*, and it describes how a unit volume in the space is dilated or shrunk by the linear operator.  There is no need to resort to a matrix representation to do this, nor must we choose a specific basis to know this is so.